# Are there any standard formats for storing/publishing GPS data?

Tags: gps

I’m just playing about with the data from a little Garmin GPS thingy I got. It saves it in an XML format (specifically, http://www.garmin.com/xmlschemas/TrainingCenterDatabasev2.xsd).

Just wondering if there was any more standard format I could convert it to, maybe something that libraries (e.g. the Google Maps API) would understand.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you're looking for is probably [KML](http://code.google.com/apis/kml/documentation/). Its pretty easy to use, just check it out.

Answer (score 8):

Try KML:

http://code.google.com/apis/kml/documentation/

This can be consumed by many mapping APIs, including Google Maps and Google Earth, and there are many tools to convert to/from other GPS formats.

Comment: Stack Overflow freaking rocks. Well played chaps.

Answer (score 6):

[GPX](http://www.topografix.com/gpx.asp) has been out there for a while.

Comment: The only open standard around.

Comment: GPX stores timestamped points, and KML doesn't. That means you can only analyze things as speed, or the location you had at a certain time of day, or how much time / average speed you took from point A to B along the trajectory, you should use GPX instead of KML.

Answer (score 4):

KML GPX CSV and many other formats are available, you can try GPSBABEL http://www.gpsbabel.org/ to convert from one format to another, it supports almost all major formats.

Comment: GPS Babel kicks ass! Reading its exhausive docs about gps file formats is a hobby on its own!